# django models getting queryset

Tags: django

how to get status_updation and status_date respect to the order_number

```
class customer_database(models.Model):

    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    customer_email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_id


class order_database(models.Model):

    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    order_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    order_consignment_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    order_customer = models.ForeignKey(customer_database, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number


class track_database(models.Model):

    order_status = models.ForeignKey(order_database, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_updation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status_updation
```

Comment: You have to be more verbose in your description of your problem.

Comment: could you explain in detail about what you mean with `how to get status_updation and status_date respect to the order_number`?

Comment: @KingReload I think s/he mean that how can we get the status of an order and timestamp by using the order number

Comment: Yes it is , umair is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
query_order_number = '1234'
tracker = track_database.objects.filter(order_status.order_number = query_order_number)
print(tracker.status_updation)
print(tracker.status_timestamp)
```

Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: it didnt work. it gave a syntax error. saying that keyword cannot be an expression

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go via the order number:

```
query_order_number = '1234'
order = order_database.objects.filter(order_number = query_order_number)
print(order.track_database.status_updation)
print(order.track_database.status_timestamp)
```

Comment: getting attribute error. saying queryset object has no attribute 'track_database'